# text not displayed in textview

Tags: android, textview

I am calling setmessage function from gpstracking.java to set the textview value in a new intent but nothing gets displayed when i run it. I dont know what is the error.
I am posting the code.I am using setText to set the value.I am sending the latitude and longitude as the parameter to the function.

gpstracking.java

```
package com.example.gpstracking;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity {  
    Button btnShowLocation;

    // GPSTracker class
    GPSTracker gps;
    List<Address> addresses;
    @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
       final Intent i;
       i=new Intent(this,SMS.class);
        // show location button click event
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {        
                // create class object
                gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

            // check if GPS enabled     
                if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    // \n is for new line   
                Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                    try{
                    List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

                    if (addresses.size() > 0) 
                    {
                        SMS.setmessage(latitude,longitude);
                    }
                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.print(e);
                    }
                }else{
                    // can't get location
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

SMS.java

```
    package com.example.gpstracking;
import com.example.gpstracking.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class SMS extends Activity {
    Button btnSendSMS;
    EditText phone_number;
    static TextView message;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.smsmain);
        btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendmessage);
        phone_number= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
        message=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                String phoneNo = phone_number.getText().toString();
                String msg = message.getText().toString();
                if (phoneNo.length()>0)// && message.length()>0)                
                    sendSMS(phoneNo, msg);                
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });  
            }               


private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{      
    /*
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, test.class), 0);                
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
    */

    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    //---when the SMS has been sent---
   registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
               case android.telephony.SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case android.telephony.SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case android.telephony.SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case android.telephony.SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    //---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;                      
            }
        }
     }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);               
} 
public static void setmessage(double latitude,double longitude)
{

    message.setText("my lat long is"+latitude+longitude);
}
}
```

Comment: I hope you're doing this with the user's consent man.

Comment: why you do't try a else case for another message

Comment: I have added the permissions man

Comment: Have you debug and checked if the setmessage() method is being called?

Comment: also ensure tat ur background and text colors are different

Comment: try on Android level 2.3.1 above phone... i think there is an exception thrown because the address was not found.. and that is why the method is not called at all.. there seems to be nothing wrong in your method to set the text..

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Put the latitude and longitude to next activity and get it.

```
Intent I = new Intent(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this, SMS.class);
I.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
I.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
startActivity(I);
```

get this lat and lng for next class.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
lat = i.getStringExtra("latitude");
lng = i.getStringExtra("longitude");
```

**EDITED YOUR CODE:**

```
public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity {  
Button btnShowLocation;

// GPSTracker class
GPSTracker gps;
List<Address> addresses;
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

    // show location button click event
    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {        
            // create class object
            gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

        // check if GPS enabled     
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                // \n is for new line   
            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                try{
                List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

                if (addresses.size() > 0) 
                {
                    SMS.setmessage(latitude,longitude);
                }
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.print(e);
                }
            }else{
                // can't get location
                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }
             final Intent i;
   i=new Intent(this,SMS.class);
   i.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
i.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
```

And then get Your lat and lng inside the SMS.class `onCreate`. you will get value

Comment: i copied the location to a variable and used that in SMS.java and now its working.